# DeSerialize using Json.net

Tags: json, json.net

Please help to deserialise

```
[
    "newdatabase",
    "testdb"
]
```

using `json.net`.

`DbList dblist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbList>(GetdbResponse.Content)`

not working for the above `json`. It showing error.

```
{   "dblist":
     [
         "newdatabase",
         "testdb"
     ] }
```

But the above json will work without any problem

Comment: `["newdatabase","testdb"]` is an array. Not a JSON.

Comment: @SreekeshOkky It is valid JSON array.  Try it yourself at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: @BrianRogers Still in your answer you handled it as a List not as a JSON

Comment: @SreekeshOkky The term "JSON" stands for JavaScript Object Notation.  It is a data interchange format that includes both arrays and objects.  So it *is* JSON, although it is not a JSON *object*.  See http://www.json.org/.

Comment: @BrianRogers I got that. What I was trying to say is that he may have to consider that as an array instead of JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first JSON represents an array of strings, so you need to deserialize into a `List<string>`.  Try it like this:

```
List<string> dblist = 
             JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(GetdbResponse.Content);
```

The second JSON represents an object that *contains* a list of strings.  In that case you would deserialize it into a class like this, using the code you have in your question:

```
class DbList
{
    public List<string> dblist { get; set; }
}
```